# excel 2007: append certain characters to value in a column to make it proper lenght

Tags: excel-2007

I have following values in a column :

123
456
789
65
1

I want to append correct number of zeros in all the values in that column such that the total length of character is 5.

00123
00456
00789
00065
00001

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is one number per cell, you can do this easily by changing the format to "Custom."

1. Right-click on the cells you would like to format.
2. From the context menu, choose "Format cells"
3. Choose the Custom category.
4. Over the word "General," in the Type textbox, enter 00000. (This tells Excel to print with
   leading 0s).
5. Click OK.

If the number is bigger than five digits, it will print all of the digits.

===EDIT===
You explained that these were all in one cell. @paulmorriss has an excellent Excel-function-only solution, but let me proffer a VBA solution as an alternative:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim txt As String
  Dim asWords() As String
  Dim zeros As String

  txt = vbNullString
  asWords = Split(Range("A1").Value) 'asWords(0)="123" etc.
  For i = 0 To UBound(asWords) ' emulate StrDup (missing in VBA)
    zeros = vbNullString
    For j = Len(asWords(i)) + 1 To 5: zeros = zeros + "0": Next j
  txt = txt + zeros + asWords(i) + " "
  Next i

  Range("B1").Value = txt 'Places answer in B1
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a list of n (5) numbers in each cell, the "Format cells" feature applies to the (whole) cell.

Answer (score 0):

If the value you specify is in cell A1 then put the following formulae in B1 to K1. The value in K1 is what you need. You could specify one massive formula, but it's easier for people maintaining the spreadsheet to see what's going on if it's split up like this.

> in B1 =TEXT(VALUE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1))),"000000")
>
> in C1 =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1))
>
> etc. =TEXT(VALUE(LEFT(C1,SEARCH(" ",C1))),"000000")
>
> =RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-SEARCH(" ",C1))
>
> =TEXT(VALUE(LEFT(E1,SEARCH(" ",E1))),"000000")
>
> =RIGHT(E1,LEN(E1)-SEARCH(" ",E1))
>
> =TEXT(VALUE(LEFT(G1,SEARCH(" ",G1))),"000000")
>
> =RIGHT(G1,LEN(G1)-SEARCH(" ",G1))
>
> =TEXT(I1,"000000")
>
> =B1&" "&D1&" "&F1&" "&H1&" "&J1